# I want to get the unique data from the file removing duplicates

Tags: unix

Iam trying to get unique data from the file containing duplicates.

here is the file sample.txt with the data as below.

```
01|128
01|132
02|124
02|258
03|858
03|788
04|418
04|129
05|328
05|398
```

i want to get only unique data based on the column ie only one entry for 01|,
 02|, 03|,04|,05|

```
grep -m1 

grep: illegal option -- m
```

i tried using m1 option but it doesn't support

I/P:sample.txt

```
01|128
01|132
02|124
02|258
03|858
03|788
04|418
04|129
05|328
05|398
```

Expected O/P

```
01|128
02|124
03|858
04|418
05|328
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can be done with:

```
sort -nu
```

`-n` says to use numeric comparison (so `01|...` will be treated as `1`, `02|...` as `2`, etc). `-u` only outputs the first line of a run of equal elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot  i was going around grep awk and uniq to get this done until this. It worked fine for my huge file as well 

Comment: POSIX [`sort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html)
doesn't guarantee the first in the group behaviour that GNU [`sort(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) and the sort provided on macOS (version `2.3-Apple (99)`) do guarantee.  That presumably isn't a problem for the OP since this is accepted.  You still get a +1 from me, though.

Comment: @KarthikReddy Possible awk solution: `awk -F '|' '!seen[$1]++'`

Comment: @melpomene which is recommended when the file size is huge, grep or awk?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler either grep or awk which will process faster for a huge file

Comment: @KarthikReddy — Since `grep` doesn’t do the job you want, `awk` is the better solution.